# Linux and basic docker configuration

Tags: php, linux, docker

I have this snippet in my Dockerfile

```
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

but my php.ini is in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`

When I run:

```
COPY /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

I get the error saying no directory

How do I define the path of my `php.ini`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference files that are outside of the directory where your Dockerfile is. You need to copy your php.ini file to that directory. This is by design. All of the files in that directory are actually sent to the host where the docker daemon is running. It's called the "context" for the build. The Dockerfile instructions are run on that host, not your local machine.

See the official site for the details. Search for "context".
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/